# How to get the current URL within a LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView (Django template)?

Tags: django, templates, url, view, updates

I want to edit a data. For that I have to click on a button from my main page. I would like by clicking on the edit button, send the url to the page edition. And once I finish the changes, I'll want to go back to my main page.

**Here is the sequence of actions in pictures:**

[image]

*---------------------------------------*

[image]

**Here is the view:**

```
class A_UpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'page_form.html'
    login_url = '/login/'
    form_class = A_Form
    model = Team
    def form_valid(self, form):
        g_urls = self.request.POST.get('id_path')
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.last_user = self.request.user.username
        self.object = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('g_urls')
```

**Here is the template:**

```
<form class="btn-group" id="login_form" method="get" action="{% url 'A_UpdateView' pk=f.pk %}">
      <input type="hidden" name="id_path" id="id_path"  value = "{{ request.build_absolute_uri  }}"  >
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="aaa" name="aa" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Here is the template to edit:**

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<!--{{form.as_p}} -->
<table class="table table-bordered table-fit"  border="0" >
{{ form }}
</table>
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">OK</button>
</form>
```

Thank.